# Passing nil into offset, after iOS 9 update, freezes app (Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument)

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a Sprite Kit game in the app store that worked perfectly before the iOS 9 update. With my iPhone updated to iOS 9, the game now freezes forever when the player loads a scene that contains this code:

```
[SKConstraint orientToNode:bodyB.node offset:nil]];
```

Getting rid of this from the source code allows the game to work just like before. However, I need this line of code for a specific in-game function.

Xcode is throwing out an error beside this line of code that says this: "Null passed to a callee that requires a non-null argument". Fair enough. But then what kind of argument do I pass into the "offset:"? I've tried [SKRange rangeWithNoLimits] but the game still freezes. Any idea what to do?

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the method?  Since you don't want to offset the rotation you need to pass a range of 0 radians - `[SKRange rangeWithConstantValue:0]`